# work-around to start the linux service after StartLimitBurst exceeded

Tags: linux, service, redhat, heartbeat

The heartbeat service is not started after couple of restarted since it has reached the maximum limit defined it seems. From `/var/log/messages` and `system heartbeat status`, I found the below output. How to start the service if it has reached the maximum attempt without restarting the server because I can not restart the server since it is the prod box.

```
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com heartbeat: Exiting: error loading config file: yaml: line 19: did not find expected key
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: heartbeat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: Unit heartbeat.service entered failed state.
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: heartbeat.service failed.
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: heartbeat.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: start request repeated too quickly for heartbeat.service
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: Failed to start heartbeat.
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: Unit heartbeat.service entered failed state.
May 30 05:18:11 servername.domain.com systemd: heartbeat.service failed.
May 30 05:20:01 servername.domain.com systemd: Started Session 194726 of user root.
May 30 05:20:01 servername.domain.com systemd: Starting Session 194726 of user root.
```

Please suggest a way to bring the service up and running.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you could use:

`systemctl reset-failed`.